# ¿Cómo puedo concatenar objetos de tal manera que quede ordenado?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto, javascript-metodo

Me dieron dos arreglos como parámetros, el cual uno tiene nombre y email, otro tiene email (una propiedad duplicada) y attendances, el ejercicio debe retornar un arreglo así

```
[
    { name: 'Samuel', email: 'Samuel@hotmail.com', attendance: true },
    { name: 'Jesus', email: 'Jesus@gmail.com', attendance: false }
]
```

Mi solución hasta ahora fue quitarle la propiedad email al primer arreglo, de tal manera que solo quede la propiedad name, y así concatenarlo con el segundo arreglo, pero me falta ese último paso para concatenar de la manera correcta

También me pasa que en el if he querido usar la variable user, y al imprimirla o querer retornarla sólo me pone True, eso me ha quitado algunas opciones para concatenar que tenía en mente

[image: Ejercicio runJS]

Comment: Hola Samuel, bienvenido, la pregunta/respuesta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, te sugiero que la edites, y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, para que no sea cerrada, y evitar recibir votos negativos,mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y obtener una medalla!.

Comment: Al eliminar la imagen tu pregunta es aun menos clara, la imagen debes reemplazarla por el mismo código pero en texto, que vamos es copiar/pegar

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar `map()` en conjunto con `find()`

```js
let estudiantes = [
  { name: 'Samuel', email: 'Samuel@hotmail.com' },
  { name: 'Jesus', email: 'Jesus@gmail.com' }
]

let asistencias = [
  { email: 'Samuel@hotmail.com', attendance: true },
  { email: 'Jesus@gmail.com', attendance: false }
]

let estudiantes_asistencias = estudiantes.map(estud => {
  return {...estud, attendance: asistencias.find(asist => 
    asist.email === estud.email).attendance
  }
})

console.log(estudiantes_asistencias)
```

Esta solución asume que siempre el arreglo 'estudiantes' tendrá su correspondiente entrada en 'asistencias'

Answer (score 2):

En tu codigo lo unico que estabas haciendo es recorrer y borrar elementos de los objetos que estaban en el arreglo.
te reescribi tu codigo donde almaceno los datos en un nuevo arreglo. Si lo que necesitabas era modificar los arreglos originales hazmelo saber.

```js
let estudiantes = [
    {name: 'Samuel', email: 'Samuel@hotmail.com'},
    {name: 'Jesus', email: 'Jesus@gmail.com'}
];

let asistencias = [
    {email: 'Samuel@hotmail.com', attendence : true },
    {email: 'Jesus@gmail.com', attendence: false }   
];

function mergeData(users, attendences){ 
    let mergedData = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) { // recorremos el arreglo asistencias
        let user = users[i];
        let attendance = attendences.find(att => att.email === user.email); // Con el metodo find buscamos coincidencias por email
        
        if (attendance) { // si hay coincidencia devuelve el dato y si no la hay retorna undefined
            mergedData.push({
                name: user.name,
                email: user.email,
                attendance: attendance.attendence
            });
        }
    }
    return mergedData; // Finalmente devolvemos otro array con los objetos
}
console.log(mergeData(estudiantes,asistencias));
 
 /* Devuelve este arreglo de objetos:

 [
    { name: 'Samuel', email: 'Samuel@hotmail.com', attendance: true },
    { name: 'Jesus', email: 'Jesus@gmail.com', attendance: false }
 ]
 
  */
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero creamos la lista que vamos a devolver :

```
let nuevoUsuario = [];
```

luego, con un for, recorremos una de las listas y en cada iteración, creamos un diccionario

```
diccionario = {};
```

Para instanciarlo, agregamos la propiedad **name** de **estudiantes** y **attendance** de **attendances**, luego verificamos que el diccionario **users[ i ]**, tenga la propiedad **"email"**, en base a esta comprobación, tomamos esa propiedad de el, o de **attendances**, finalmente agregamos el diccionario a la lista:

```
diccionario.name = users[ i ].name;
diccionario.attendance = attendances[ i ].attendance
if( users[ i ].email ) {                 
   diccionario.email = users[ i ].email;                
}
else {               
   diccionario.email = attendances[ i ].email;                
}

nuevoUsuario.push( diccionario );
```

finalmente el código quedaría sí:

```js
function mergeData( users, attendances ) {
    let nuevoUsuario = [];
    for( let i = 0; i < users.length; i++ ) {           
        dic = {};
        dic.name = users[ i ].name;
        dic.attendance = attendances[ i ].attendance
        if( users[ i ].email ) {                 
            dic.email = users[ i ].email;                
        }
        else {               
            dic.email = attendances[ i ].email;                
        }
        nuevoUsuario.push( dic );
    }
    return nuevoUsuario;
}    

let estudiantes = [
  { name: 'Samuel', email: 'Samuel@hotmail.com' },
  { name: 'Jesus', email: 'Jesus@gmail.com' }
];

let asistencias = [
  { email: 'Samuel@hotmail.com', attendance: true },
  { email: 'Jesus@gmail.com', attendance: false }
];

console.log( mergeData( estudiantes, asistencias ));
```